# If I remove one child div, the other child div in parent div should change the background color

Tags: css

I have a parent `div.somename`. In that `div.somename`, I have two children `div.sub`s, each with `background-color:green`.

My question is, if I remove one of the `div.sub`s, the other `div.sub` should change the background color to blue.

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: Can you use Jquery or only CSS is what you want?

Comment: how do you remove one child with only css? That is new to me, I need javascript for that and when you are using javascript so or so, then you can change the css of the other div also per javascript

Comment: @Pavan Sven is correct here , Javascript is required to achieve this.

Comment: Actually the child div will remove by dynamically through jsp(java). I  would like to give that css without using of javascript. I am trying to do that by CSS only.

Comment: @Pavan java is not able to remove something dynamically. You have a full postback and page reload when you do it on server side. That means you can also change the css properties from the back end.

Comment: if you're removing a div on the server-side, couldn't you just change the CSS class of another div at the same time?

Comment: We can change that. But i am trying why shouldn't we do that through css.

Comment: @Pavan because css is not dynamic, there is no possibility for "when this happens, then change that"

Comment: What browsers are you targeting?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with CSS using the [`only-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#only-child-pseudo) pseudo class:

```
div.somename > div.sub {
  background-color: green;
}

div.somename > div.sub:only-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but IE<9 unfortunately won't like that.

Comment: @PavanKumar IE9+, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome. What browser are you targeting?

Comment: I need ie8 minimum. Remaining are fine

Comment: I think instead of :only-child we can mention :first-child also. Right?

Comment: @PavanKumar Nope, `:first-child` will also select the first div before you remove it. Try using [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) or a similar framework to enable advanced selectors in internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fant/SVw7r/)

Comment: Nice use of sibling combinators. However, note that this only works if you're always removing the first box. Doesn't work if you remove the second one

Comment: What does ~ indication means?

Comment: It's called the 'general sibling selector' and matches elements that are siblings of a given element. Unfortunately just following siblings.